# DOM: Forcing inheritance of class attribute from parent

Tags: javascript, html, class, dom

Say, an HTML file contains the following elements:

```
<div class="mydiv">  
    <img src="img.jpg"/>  
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is safe to programmatically transform it into

```
<img class="mydiv" src="img.jpg" />
```

That is, adding the parent's class to the child element and ripping the parent itself.
Do the two versions of HTML code yield the same rendering when a CSS rule is present for the class? If not, which are the cases when it does not happen in fact?

**Notes:**
-the parent just features the class, it has no other meaningful attributes
-the CSS files cannot be altered
-the transformation is performed by javascript after the HTML is loaded
-the goal is getting rid of the parent but so that all CSS rules render the same

Comment: `div`s have `display:block` by default, `img`s in the other hand are `inline` (in strict mode).

Comment: Let alone your question lacks many details, e.g. your new `.mydiv` img will not inherit a `.mydiv img` which previously was present.

Comment: You're just creating more work for yourself. As Fabrício Matté says. Just leave it alone if it works. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the title of the question first: classes are never inherited. CSS rules can be.

There are a couple of general cases where things could go wrong.

There might be rules which only apply under certain conditions (e.g. `margin: auto` has different effects depending on the value of `display` (which has different defaults for different elements).

Selectors might be more specific that `.mydiv`. There might be `div.mydiv` or `.mydiv img`

Answer (score 0):

No, not all CSS declarations cascade downwards. Which ones cascade and how they cascade depends on the browser.

Comment: Err. No. The cascade is implemented very consistently across browsers.

Comment: Maybe in theory. But in practice, I find this hard to believe.

Comment: No, in practice. They've had a long time to get it right. The cascade rules are not that complex.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason for the class being in the DIV is solely to define properties unique to the image, then YES you can swap out and the behavior should be the same. You will also have to update your CSS to make sure you handle this new class assignment.

However. Make sure that the DIV assignment is not there to establish context. That is, there may be other IMGs in the HTML that could now be covered by the new class assignment.

div.mydiv>img is a more specific scenario than img.mydiv

Also that parent div may be covered by another similar CSS rule of broader scope.